# SQL AWS Athena Group by Without a Column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have this dataset

```
patient_id   doctor_id   status   created_at
1            1           A        2020-10-01 10:00:00
1            1           P        2020-10-01 10:30:00
1            1           U        2020-10-01 10:35:00
1            2           A        2020-10-01 10:40:00
...
```

I want to group it by patient_id and doctor_id but without the status is grouped so the result will be like this

```
patient_id   doctor_id   status   created_at
1            1           U        2020-10-01 10:35:00
1            2           A        2020-10-01 10:40:00
...
```

AWS Athena have to grouped all column but I need the last status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` provides one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id, doctor_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT patient_id, doctor_id, status, created_at
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY patient_id, doctor_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Athena/Presto you can do this with the [`max_by`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#max_by) function:

```sql
SELECT
  patient_id,
  doctor_id,
  MAX_BY(status, created_at) AS last_status
FROM the_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

`max_by(x, y)` function returns the value of the column `x` for the row with the max value of column `y` of the group.